# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos de un formulario dinámico con javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando una vista previa del formulario antes de insertar los datos mi problema es que solo me muestra los datos de los primeros selects pero los generados dinámicamente no los muestra (tabla dinámica con selects)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<tr>
  <th>Area</th>
  <th>Nombre</th>
  <th></th>
</tr>

<tr class="fila2">
  <td><select name="area[]" class="login-input" id="area" required="">
      <option disabled selected value="">Area de trabajo:</option>
      <option value="maquinas">Maquinas</option>
      <option value="encuadernacion">Encuadernacion</option>
      <option value="acabado">Acabado</option>
    </select> 
  </td>

  <td> 
  <select name="personal[]" class="login-input" id="personal" required="" >
    <option disabled selected value="">Nombre del trabajador:</option>
    <?php
      $rows2=$optionsmodel->getPersonal(); 
      $options_nombre='';
      foreach ($rows2 as $row) { 
      $options_nombre.='<option 
      value="'.$row['usuario'].'">'.$row['usuario'].'</option>';                             
    ?>  
    <option value="<?php echo $row['usuario'];?>"> 
    <?php echo $row['usuario'];?>     
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</td>
```

código del select nombre así con todos los demás selects) vista previa al insertar todos los datos se aprecia que solo muestra los primeros los demás los ignora 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se muestra el código de la vita previa elaborada en `javascript`

```
 $(document).on("submit","#form-velada",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.cotizador_box').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'linear');
  $('.backdrop').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
  $('.backdrop, .cotizador_box').css('display', 'block');

  html='<p><span>fecha:</span><p>';
  var fecha = $("#letra2").val();
  html+= ""+fecha;

  html+='<p><span>Autorizo:</span><p>';
  var autorizo = $("#autorizo").val()

  html+= ""+autorizo;

  html+='<p><span>Responsable:</span><p>';
  var responsable = $("#responsable").val();
  html+= ""+responsable;

  html+='<p><span>Personal:</span><p>';
  var area = $("#area").val();
  var personal = $("#personal").val();
  html+= ""+area+"   ";
  html+= ""+personal;   
  html+='<p><span>Ordenes:</span><p>';

  var descripcion = $("#descripcion").val();
  var ODT = $("#ODT").val();

  html+= ""+descripcion+"   ";
  html+= ""+ODT;

  html+='<p><span>Gastos:</span><p>'; 

  var gasto = $("#gasto").val();
  var costo = $("#costo").val();

  html+= ""+gasto+"   ";
  html+= ""+costo;

  $('#resumen').append(html);
});

$(document).on("click","#cancelar",function(e){
  closeModal();
});

$(document).on("click","#guardar",function(e){
  $('.cotizador_box').hide();
  $('.loader').show();
  $.ajax({   çç
```

como puedo mostrar los datos que generados dinamicamente aydaaaaaaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No uses el atributo de id, porque serian múltiples valores con el mismo id, prueba con "name", algo como lo siguiente:

```js
var areas = $("input[name='area\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
alert(areas);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="area" name="area[]" value="Encuadernacion" />
<input type="text" id="area" name="area[]" value="Maquinas" />
<input type="text" id="area" name="area[]" value="Encuadernacion" />
```

Comment: y si son selects? no son inputs

Comment: si me sirvio gracias bro remplaze el input por select y ya